# Integrating button to change divergent bar chart in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm a complete newbie to d3and trying to create a divergent bar chart with an update button. I've gotten this far with modifying other people's code but seem to have broken it somewhere along the way!

Code as below:

```
`<style>
 body { margin:0; position:fixed; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; }

 body {
   font-family: Arial;
}

.y-axis line{
  stroke: black;
}

.annual-growth {
  fill: black;
}

.bar-label, .x-axis {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.domain, .tick line {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```
<body>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update('var1')">Male</button>
<button onclick="update('var2')">Female</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
var margin = {top: 40, right: 50, bottom: 60, left: 50};

var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Config
var cfg = {
  labelMargin: 5,
  xAxisMargin: 10,
  legendRightMargin: 0
}

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var colour = d3.scaleSequential().domain([1,10])
.interpolator(d3.interpolatePuRd);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 20])
    .padding(0.15);

function parse(d) {
  d.rank = +d.rank;
  d.[selectedVar] = +d.[selectedVar];
  return d;
}

var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend");

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - cfg.legendRightMargin)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Ethnicity");

legend.append("text")
// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(selectedVar) {
  .attr("x", width - cfg.legendRightMargin)
    .attr("y", 18)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .text("Incidence(Per 100,000)");

// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(selectedVar) {

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apexmedicine/D3/master/demographics7.csv", parse, 
function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Group; }));
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.[selectedVar]; }));
  
  var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.[selectedVar]; });
  colour.domain([-max, max]);
  
  var yAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",80)")
    .append("line")
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("y2", height);
  
  var xAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + cfg.xAxisMargin) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
  
// variable u: map data to existing bars
var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)

// update bars
u
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .merge(u)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Group); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[selectedVar]); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d[selectedVar]); })
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")

  var labels = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
  
  labels.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "bar-label")
    .attr("x", x(0))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Group )})
    .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return d.Group < 0 ? cfg.labelMargin : -cfg.labelMargin;
    })
    .attr("dy", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "start" : "end";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.Group })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
         if (d.Ethhnicity == "Black") {
         return "blue";
       }
    });
    
});
}  

// Initialize plot
update('var1')

</script>
</body>`
```

I want it to look something along the lines of this:

[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocsd5.png)

I've tried to make this work for days - could anyone help? What do I need to add/change/delete?

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi, seems like your code has some mistakes, for example `function update(selectedVar) { .attr("x", width - cfg.legendRightMargin)` didn't make sense, missing the selection before `.attr`. also you have use dot notation and bracket notation at the same time. Please provide executable code then it will be easier to locate the problem.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/diverging-bar-chart) of diverging horizontal barchart, maybe helpful to build code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change some part of your code to make it works, but not perfectly functional.

1. use dot notation or bracket notation, but not both

```
// not
d[selectedVar] = +d.[selectedVar];
// use
d[selectedVar] = +d[selectedVar];
```

2. `parse()` function has no idea what `selectedVar` is, and since both `var1` and `var2` are useful, try to parse them both.

```
function parse(d) {
  d.rank = +d.rank;
  d.var1 = +d.var1;
  d.var2 = +d.var2;
  return d;
}
```

3. the misuse of `x()` and `y()` for building rects, the width is related to the value and the height is related to the `y.bandwidth()`

Here is the [executable code](https://jsfiddle.net/98c1utkz/78/), maybe not fully suit your need but you can make more edits to get what you want.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- Add 2 buttons -->
<button onclick="update('var1')">Male</button>
<button onclick="update('var2')">Female</button>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
var margin = {top: 40, right: 50, bottom: 60, left: 50};

var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Config
var cfg = {
  labelMargin: 5,
  xAxisMargin: 10,
  legendRightMargin: 0
}

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var colour = d3.scaleSequential().domain([1,10])
.interpolator(d3.interpolatePuRd);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 20])
    .padding(0.15);

function parse(d) {
  d.rank = +d.rank;
  d.var1 = +d.var1;
  d.var2 = +d.var2;
  return d;
}

var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend");

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - cfg.legendRightMargin)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Ethnicity");

legend.append("text")
// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
  .attr("x", width - cfg.legendRightMargin)
    .attr("y", 18)
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .text("Incidence(Per 100,000)");

// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
var yAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
  
  var xAxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis");
    
var labels = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");
function update(selectedVar) {

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apexmedicine/D3/master/demographics7.csv", parse, 
function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Group; }));
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[selectedVar]; }));
  
  if(x.domain()[1] < 0) x.domain([x.domain()[0], 0])
  
  var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[selectedVar]; });
  colour.domain([-max, max]);
  
  yAxis.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",80)")
    .append("line")
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", height);
  
  xAxis.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + cfg.xAxisMargin) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
  
// variable u: map data to existing bars
var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
// update bars
 u
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
   .merge(u)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x(Math.min(d[selectedVar], 0)); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
    return y(d.Group); })
    .attr("width", d=>{
        return Math.abs(x(d[selectedVar]) - x(0))})
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")

 
  
  let text_u = labels.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    text_u.enter()
    .append("text")
    .merge(text_u)
    .attr("class", "bar-label")
    .attr("x", x(0))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Group )})
    .attr("dy", y.bandwidth() / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d[selectedVar] < 0 ? "start" : "end";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.Group })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
         if (d.Ethhnicity == "Black") {
         return "blue";
       }
    });
    
});
}  

// Initialize plot
update('var1')

</script>
</body>
```